# In Ruby on Rails, how do I pass control to an action in another controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have found several references that describe the difference between `render` and `redirect_to`, but none that let me know how to do exactly what I want, which is to pass control directly (within this same request, so no `redirect_to`) to an action in another controller.

Basically, I want to fix a bug in the sample code that I'm using for handling logins and sessions.  If I log in, but then later do a `rake db:seed`, it changes all of the IDs for users, and my login session becomes invalid.  This causes a nasty exception to be thrown when I try to get the current user, with this:

```
@current_user ||= Reviewer.find(session[:reviewer_id])
```

So to fix it, I want to put a check in my "before_filter", `ensure_login`.  Something like this (but this does not work):

```
unless Reviewer.where(id: session[:reviewer_id]).first
  render :action => 'sessions/destroy'
end
```

This attempts to render the *template* associated with `sessions/destroy`, but of course there isn't one.  I think the solution must be something very simple, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution isn't to instantiate another controller and call an action on that (poor organization and too much overhead), but to put the code you want to call in some commonly accessible location, like a helper or lib file, e.g.:

```
# in a controller
unless ...
  render_session_destroy
end

# in a relevant helper
def render_session_destroy
   ...
end
```

Then `render_session_destroy` can *also* be called from its original controller.

Comment: I often put code like this in my `ApplicationController` since all controllers inherit from that. It does end up being a junk drawer sometimes, but I think it's a good place for shared authentication-related methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use of redirect_to

For example

`redirect_to '/SignOut'`

In routes like

```
  resources :user_sessions
  match '/SignOut', to: 'user_sessions#destroy'
```